# Firefox ignores percentage width value set for text input element

Tags: css, forms, firefox, input

In the screenshots, the form text fields are set to 97% to create a gap between them. It works in all browsers except Firefox -- it seems it stretches all the way to 100%. Anyone pls give me a way to get around this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by input element?  About section on page blank, and one search box?

Comment: Can you attach some screen shots showing what area that needs changed, that website will change over time so the question will be irrelevant for future users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `box-sizing: border-box` (and the corresponding `-moz-box-sizing`, `-webkit-box-sizing`). Otherwise, padding and margin are added to the 97% instead of included in.

Answer (score 0):

I am using FF 13.0.1 on Mac OS and the gap shows correctly.

[image]

Comment: OK, I see you want a larger gap. Why not style the inputs with a border?